# Filter out indexes with mapped types

Tags: typescript

I've been looking at this code ([source](https://dev.to/busypeoples/notes-on-typescript-conditional-types-4bh)) for a moment now and can't get its syntax at all. Up until now, I didn't know it was possible to filter out indexes. I understand what it does but I just don't understand its syntax.

```
type RemoveUndefinable<T> = { //<--- what I don't understand
  [Key in keyof T]: undefined extends T[Key] ? never : Key
}[keyof T]; //--> what does the appended [keyof T] mean here? what does RemoveUndefinable return?

type RemoveNullableProperties<T> = {
  [Key in RemoveUndefinable<T>]: T[Key]
};

type TestRemoveNullableProperties = RemoveNullableProperties<{
  id: number;
  name: string;
  property?: string;
}>;
```

I understand we may also do something like this, which is even more mysterious.

```
type Test<T> = T[RemoveUndefinable<T>]
```

May someone help shed some light on this, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it.

```
type RemoveUndefinable<T> = {
  [Key in keyof T]: undefined extends T[Key] ? never : Key
}[keyof T]; //--> that's lookup
```

So, say we have a type

```
type MyType = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  property?: string;
}
```

RemoveUndefinable produces

```
{
  id: "id"
  name: "name"
  property?: never
}["id" | "name" | "property"] // "id" | "name" | undefined
```

And this

```
MyType[RemoveUndefinable<MyType>]
```

is equivalent to

```
MyType["id" | "name" | undefined]
```